# I can't seem to add a close button using Qt::WindowFlags

Tags: c++, qt4

I have the following code that is called when I insert a QMdiSubWindow into a QMdiArea:

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags;

flags = Qt::Widget | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint;

if(closeable)
{
    qDebug("Window is closeable. %x", Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
    flags |= Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint;
}
```

For some reason, even when closeable is true, the closebutton won't display on the widget's titlebar.

This is the call to insert the widget into the QMdiArea.

```
mdi->addSubWindow(widget, flags);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you calling setWindowFlags(flags)?

Comment: @Greg Really? I didn't intend it to be. @omrib, I'm calling addSubWindow() with the flags.

Comment: Which OS are you using? On Windows I don't see this problem, but unless I use Qt::CustomizeWindowHint I get the close button even if it's not mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04, Qt 4.6.2. I'll see if it pops up on any of the other build boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that playing around with the window flags example included with the sdk was a lot of help when trying to get the flags correct.

C:\QtSDK\Examples\4.7\widgets\windowflags\

Comment: On second thought it looks like they don't have a QMdiSubWindow type.